# dynamic_template_data not working when sending dynamic template using curl request - Sendgrid API

Tags: email, curl, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm making a curl request to send dynamic template with handlebar but it's not working properly.

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer SG.xxxxxxxx.v-8xxxxxxxxxxxxI' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"personalizations": [{"to": [{"email": "mrrobot@mail.com"}]}],"from": {"email": "contact@evilcorp.com"},"dynamic_template_data":{"fname":"elliot"}, "subject": "Hello, World!","content": [{"type": "text/html", "value": "Heya!"}], "template_id" : "d-xxxxxxxxxa1f"}}'
```

In my dynamic template I've used fname as `{{fname}}` but it's coming as empty when I make the curl request.

Answer (score 2):

**dynamic_template_data** should be inside **personalizations**.
E.g:

```
{
  "personalizations": [
    {
      "to": [
        {
          "email": "mrrobot@mail.com"
        }
      ],
      "dynamic_template_data": {
        "fname": "elliot"
      }
    }
  ],
  "from": {
    "email": "contact@evilcorp.com"
  },
  "subject": "Hello, World!",
  "content": [
    {
      "type": "text/html",
      "value": "Heya!"
    }
  ],
  "template_id": "d-xxxxxxxxxa1f"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same issue but as per the [documentation](https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us/articles/1260802535110-Create-a-Dynamic-Email-Subject-Line-with-Mustache-Templates) of sendgrid, we have to update our template with the subject `{{subject}}` and pass the subject in the `dynamic_template_data`

```
 const data = {
  personalizations: [
    {
      to: [
        {
          email: invitee_email,
        },
      ],
      dynamic_template_data: {
        subject: "Write your subject here",
        ...
      },
    },
  ],
  from: {
    email: sender_email,
    name: "Some Name",
  },
  template_id: "Unique template ID",
};
```

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, subject should be specified as follows: `{{{subject}}}`